# Cassandra configuration - is native transport necessary on all cluster nodes?

Tags: configuration, cassandra

Does Cassandra require both of the following options to be on?

```
start_native_transport:                 true
start_rpc:                              true
```

Are these required on *all* Cassandra nodes?

As far as I can tell, the purpose of each is thus:

```
* native transport - for servicing CQL clients
* rpc - for cluster inter node communication
```

are these correct?
If they are, I guess I should enable rpc on all nodes, and perhaps native transport on only one node?  Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native transport is the CQL Native Protocol (as opposed to the Thrift Protocol) and is the way all modern Cassandra Driver's communicate with the server. This includes all reads/writes/schemachanges/etc

Hence you cannot make `start_native_transport` as false.